# I cannot access to some method from a service in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular **12** application. Where I have a service `FormService` to retrieve information from some forms.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormService {
  jsonUrl = './assets/forms/form.json';
  defaultForm = 'form';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private logger: LogService) {
  }


  getFormName(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
      .pipe((res: any) => res.label);
  }
  ...
```

I only show one simple method to make it simpler. I am injecting this service in the app-component `ngOnInit` to load some default information.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


constructor(
    ...
    private formService: FormService,
    ...
  ) {
  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formService.getFormName()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.formName = data;
 });
```

When I run the application, I get a simple error as:

```
this.formService.getFormName() is undefined
```

Then, I am trying to show the content of `formService` by console:

[image: method not accesble!]

According to the structure, seems that the `formService` is injected, but the methods are not generated yet. In fact, `formService` is defined, but `getFormName` not!

Why the methods are not yet accessible?

Comment: I have the impression that the issue is related to the method that is using a `http` connection. As other services are not facing this issue and are obtained correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the `http` was involved as I have imagined. Currently I am migrating this application from Angular 4 to Angular 12. And I have compared with other `http` requests in other applications I have created using Angular 12 directly.

If, I change:

```
  getFormName(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
      .pipe((res: any) => res.label);
  }
```

To something like this:

```
  getFormName(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(this.jsonUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.logger.info('fetched form!')),
        catchError(this.logger.handleError<string>('failure getting form name!'))
      );
  }
```

Or better, with a `Promise`:

```
  getFormName(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      const form: Observable<Form> = this.http.get<Form>(this.jsonUrl);
      if (form) {
        form.subscribe(content => {
          resolve(content.label);
        });
      } else {
        reject('Form not found!');
      }
    });
  }
```

It is working fine. When I use a console log I do not get the `undefined` result any more. I am not an expert in Angular, and sure not in Angular 4. But seems that the pipe defined that was working previously in Angular 4, has a different behavior in Angular 12.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app.module.ts, are you already import HttpClientModule?

Answer (score -1):

did you add this service in the providers array in app.module

Comment: Yes, sure. Is done by default when using the `ng generate service...`